# How to transfer data from CPU to GPU runtime on google colab?

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I used `files.upload()` on three hdf5 data files on Google Colab, in order to train some TensorFlow models, and it took a few minutes to complete.

Everything ran smooth with a few minor modifications from the local Jupyter notebook. However, when I proceed to change the runtime from "None" to "GPU", no files previously uploaded are present in the home folder. I just had to re-upload them. Going back to the "None" runtime showed that the files were still there.

Is there a convenient way to copy+paste the data from one runtime to another?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anyway to directly copy data from a CPU instance to a GPU one.

So, you probably need to copy it to Google Drive (or mount it with ocamlfuse).

Another way is to use git to add, and push from one. Then clone from the other.